# Monthly change images directory Drupal 8

Tags: 7, files, media

I am working on a news portal site. 
We have a lot of posts and also a lot of pictures are saved daily.

At the moment, the size of `/sites/default/files` directory is around 6GB and contains almost 23k files. And that is a problem.

What I want is to have directory for every month, for example:

```
/sites/default/files/3-17     
/sites/default/files/4-17
...
```

Does anybody know how to do this?
Also, is there a way to keep live posts working?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths
You can change path for every field type and use tokens like /[date:custom:Y]/[date:custom:m] to achive what I wanted...